# run rywa/silverstripe-foundation-forms

Tags: forms, zurb-foundation, silverstripe

I have installed rywa/silverstripe-foundation-forms with composer and my composer.json is there. I do not see how this functions. I have created a form in add foundation class `medium-6 columns`. This is my code:

```
 public function ContactForm() {
        $myForm = Form::create(
            $this,
            __FUNCTION__,
            FieldList::create(
                TextField::create('YourName','Your name'),
                TextareaField::create('YourComments','Your comments')->addExtraClass('medium-6 columns')
            ),
            FieldList::create(
                FormAction::create('sendContactForm','Submit')
            ),
            RequiredFields::create('YourName','YourComments')
        );

        return $myForm;
    }
```

The problem is the form adds a class container in the input

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass FoundationForm afaik, so doing something like:

```
public function ContactForm() {
    $myForm = FoundationForm::create(
        $this,
        __FUNCTION__,
        FieldList::create(
            TextField::create('YourName','Your name'),
            TextareaField::create('YourComments','Your comments')
            ->addExtraClass('medium-6 columns')
        ),
        FieldList::create(
            FormAction::create('sendContactForm','Submit')
        ),
        RequiredFields::create('YourName','YourComments')
    );

    return $myForm;
}
```

should work.